# Host card emulation on iOS with Private APIs?

Tags: ios, iphone, nfc, hce, core-nfc

I'm wondering how to do host card emulation on iOS. It seems very obvious this is not possible through CoreNFC (at least not through publicly exposed APIs), but I am wondering if it's possible through private APIs that are not directly exposed.

The closest thing I've seen is this jailbreak tweak, http://cydia.saurik.com/package/net.limneos.nfcwriterx/. Unfortunately, the methods this tweak uses to achieve HCE are not clear.

Wondering if there's been any research done or any known APIs to perform HCE on iOS through CoreNFC?